# Are there existing database schemas available for storing X12 837 data?

Tags: sql, x12

Are there existing database schemas available for storing X12 837 data?  Seems like there would be, versus manually recreating from scratch.

I tried Googling for X12 837 database schemas but did not find any.

Edit: the database is relational, so would need CREATE TABLE or similar SQL.  And even a schema, that I could create my own manual SQL from, would be beneficial.

Comment: This looks like a good start: https://hiplab.mc.vanderbilt.edu/git/hiplab/parser . It seems the format is classic EDI which is a pain in the terminal to do in regular SQL

Comment: Need relational schema if possible (e.g. CREATE TABLE)

Comment: I think the project i mentioned creates a table for you, but i don't know how good it is :)

Comment: Look at SmileCDR - it's a clinical repository. I think it's open source, but I don't think it's free.